# inverted curve using clip-path css

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to reproduce a design I have. I have a side navigation and want to add the little light-blue triangle at the bottom. All no issue, but I can't seem to find how to get that inverted curve into it.

[image]

What is I did is I created a div and added absolute positioning. I used clip-path to create the triangle shape, but this is where I get stuck. Anyone an idea on how to do this?

CSS:

```
     triangle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 50%
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
        height: '20%',
        clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%)',
      },
```

[image]

Comment: Use a curved clip path, they don't have to be polygons? Or an SVG background would be even better? You don't have to do this with basic CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different figures from css and html. Here is an example that can help you with your project. Create two differents files.

```css
    
    #curved-corner-bottomleft,
    #curved-corner-bottomright,
    #curved-corner-topleft,
    #curved-corner-topright {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    #curved-corner-bottomleft:before,
    #curved-corner-bottomright:before,
    #curved-corner-topleft:before,
    #curved-corner-topright:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 200%;
      height: 200%;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    #curved-corner-bottomleft:before {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      box-shadow: -50px 50px 0 0 rgba(72, 289, 245, 0.8);
    }
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="curved-corner-bottomleft" ></div>
                <div id="curved-corner-bottomright" ></div>
                <div id="curved-corner-topleft" ></div>
                <div id="curved-corner-topright" ></div>
            </body>
        </html>
```